# Adding seconds to a column that only contains Hours/Minnitues

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a piece of code that is taking data in a csv and dong some transformation in a data frame. One of the columns in this data frame contains time in a `HH:MM` format, however I need the time to return as `HH:MM:SS`.

I've tried the following.

CSV/DF example:

| Attended Time |
| --- |
| 10:01 |
| 11:40 |

**Version 1**

```
df['Attended Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Attended Time'] + ':00', df['Attended Time'])
```

and

**Version 2**

```
df['Attended Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(
np.where(df['Attended Time'].str.count(':') == 1, df['Attended Time'] + ':00', df['Attended Time']))
```

**V1** does not populate my Attended Time with the seconds and

**V2** gives me my result but adds a 0 days to the time? Anyone know why? example ***0 days 10:01:00***

Comment: it may keed seconds but not display it and you maybe need to convert to string all values using normal `strftime("%H:%m:%s")` before displaying. And even if you add `:00` and convert back to `to_timedelta` or `datetime` or `time` it may still skip seconds.

Comment: if you have as strings then you should only add `:00` without converting to `timedelta` - `df['Attended Time'] = df['Attended Time'] +':00'`

Comment: or convert to `datetime` and get `.dt.time` - `df['Attended Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Attended Time']).dt.time`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have strings then you could only add `:00`

```
df['Attended Time'] = df['Attended Time'] +':00'
```

If you want `datetime.time` objects then

```
df['Attended Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Attended Time']).dt.time
```

---

Minimal example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'A': ['10:00', '12:00', '13:00'], 
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['B'] = df['A'] +':00'

df['C'] = pd.to_datetime(df['A']).dt.time

print(df)
```

Result:

```
       A         B         C
0  10:00  10:00:00  10:00:00
1  12:00  12:00:00  12:00:00
2  13:00  13:00:00  13:00:00
```